# Configuring Jenkins build node: "Wrong password"

Tags: jenkins

We've currently got Jenkins running on a Windows virtual machine inside a Mac. I am trying to set up that Mac as a build node. I made a user, "jenkins", on that Mac for this express purpose. However, I can't SSH in to the Mac as that user (or any user) from the virtual Windows box. The Jenkins log says "Failed to authenticate as jenkins. Wrong password." I'm confident I have typed the right password, so this has me stumped.

```
[07/05/17 12:09:38] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 192.168.1.2:22.
[07/05/17 12:09:38] [SSH] The SSH key with fingerprint 9c:50:b7:ee:8e:d6:54:55:e1:76:79:1a:7a:d2:16:aa has been automatically trusted for connections to this machine.
ERROR: Failed to authenticate as jenkins. Wrong password. (credentialId:jenkinslogin/method:keyboard-interactive)
[07/05/17 12:09:38] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[07/05/17 12:09:38] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[07/05/17 12:09:38] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I tried to SSH in to the Mac from the virtual machine using PuTTY, and I get "Access denied" responses when I try to log in as user "jenkins". What's going on?

[Screenshot of Jenkins build node config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdR6k.png)

[Screenshot of user "jenkins" credentials config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxasC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved. I had to go into "System Preferences > Settings" and allow non-administrator accounts to tunnel into the user account. It's still unclear to me why I got "wrong password" as a response instead of, say, "permission denied," but that's life.